# Grails: Joda LocalDate as unique key in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, grails, jodatime

I have a domain class with a Joda LocalDate property. This property must be unique.

It works using an H2, but using a MySQL db I have this error on app boot:

```
[SchemaExport.create(l.386)]Unsuccessful: create table [...]
[SchemaExport.create(l.387)]BLOB/TEXT column 'mydate' used in key specification without a key length
```

If a remove unique constraint, it works also with MySQL.

Is it a bug or my misunderstanding?

I'm using Grails 2.2.5. 
Here domain fragment:

```
class MyClass {
    LocalDate mydate

    static constraints = {
        mydate(nullable:false, unique:true)
    }
}
```

DataSource config fragment:

```
dataSource {
    dbCreate = "create-drop"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username = "xxx"
    password = "xxx"
    dbNamer = "myapp"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${dbNamer}?autoreconnect=true"
    logSql = true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wild guess, I think that `date` is reserved word in mySQL. rename the field and try again

UPDATE:

ok, I see. 
the problem is, that GORM/Hibernate is not aware of joda `LocalDate` class, so it's trying to create a BLOB column for it:

> [SchemaExport.create(l.387)]BLOB/TEXT column 'mydate'`.

To fix it, you can either use a custom hibernate type (have no idea how), or convert the property into a plane java's `Date` class by saving, and back to `LocalDate` after loading

Comment: No, sorry: I'm using italian property names. I translated it for Stackoverflow :) .
To avoid misunderstanding, I edited my post.

Comment: They are workarounds but, after months, I thinks there is no other solution. Thank you.